# Parse logs for certain values

Tags: text-processing, logs

I am monitoring the history of convergence of a certain problem. The history output is as follows:

```
Time = 24

Calculate volume forces from actuator disk
Total thrust = -8.46832
Total torque = 1.03471
ADisk volume = 0.0632799
smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.000447755, Final residual = 2.68745e-05, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.0107909, Final residual = 0.000812227, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.0103399, Final residual = 0.000786661, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.123954, Final residual = 0.00958268, No Iterations 6
time step continuity errors : sum local = 7.42808e-05, global = -4.25546e-05, cumulative = 0.000413527
smoothSolver:  Solving for epsilon, Initial residual = 0.00197379, Final residual = 0.000172248, No Iterations 1
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.000510499, Final residual = 2.78594e-05, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 124.63 s  ClockTime = 125 s

Time = 25

Calculate volume forces from actuator disk
Total thrust = -8.49093
Total torque = 1.03723
ADisk volume = 0.0632799
smoothSolver:  Solving for Ux, Initial residual = 0.000409002, Final residual = 2.59552e-05, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uy, Initial residual = 0.0103191, Final residual = 0.00077024, No Iterations 2
smoothSolver:  Solving for Uz, Initial residual = 0.00985658, Final residual = 0.000742227, No Iterations 2
GAMG:  Solving for p, Initial residual = 0.0390756, Final residual = 0.00247253, No Iterations 7
time step continuity errors : sum local = 5.39785e-05, global = 3.40394e-05, cumulative = 0.000447566
smoothSolver:  Solving for epsilon, Initial residual = 0.00182397, Final residual = 0.000157739, No Iterations 1
smoothSolver:  Solving for k, Initial residual = 0.000465916, Final residual = 2.75864e-05, No Iterations 2
ExecutionTime = 129.45 s  ClockTime = 130 s

Time = 26

Calculate volume forces from actuator disk
Total thrust = -8.51463
Total torque = 1.03953
ADisk volume = 0.0632799
```

What I would like to do, is to copy values at a certain time, say in this case at `Time=26`, the values of

```
Total thrust = -8.51463
Total torque = 1.03953
```

in the following format:

```
1.03953 -8.51463.
```

Can someone help me to do that using shell script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked for a shell script, but hopefully `awk` will do:

#### find_thrust_torque.awk:

```
/^Total thrust =/ {thrust = $4}
/^Total torque =/ {torque = $4}
/^Time =/ {if (found) exit; if ($3 == time) found=1}
END {print torque " " thrust}
```

#### Test It:

```
$ awk -v time=25 -f find_thrust_torque.awk file1
1.03723 -8.49093

$ awk -v time=26 -f find_thrust_torque.awk file1
1.03953 -8.51463
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we single out the range of time slot plus the next one (or eof, if it's the last). This is done to avoid grabbing the next slot's data if the current slot did not have the torque/thrust numbers. So then you would be served with stale data with no error reporting around that.
The `H` command appends the pattern space to the hold space. `g` would retrieve the hold area and put it in pattern space.

```
tslot=26; # input the time you want the thrust/torque data for
sed -ne '
   /^Time = '"${tslot}"'$/,/^Time =/!d
   /^Total thrust =/{H;d;}
   /^Total torque =/{H;d;}
   g;/\n.*\n/!d
   /thrust.*torque/s/\(\n.*\)\(\n.*\)/\2\1/
   s/\n[^=]*=//gp;q
' logfile
```

---

### Result

```
1.03953 -8.51463
```